# How do I connect as newly created user through SQL Developer on Oracle Autonomous?

Tags: oracle, cloud

I have created a user(new_user) with a password.
I have granted create session to that user.
I still cannot connect to database as new_user.
ORA-01017.
I can connect as admin.

1. I can see the user(new_user) in the other users menu in SQL Developer.
2. When I go to create a table like CREATE TABLE new_user.SALES, I get ORA-01918: user 'NEW_USER' does not exist.
3. I can right-click and create a table.

I know I have the right password.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds very much like the *double quotes* issue.

Here's how it is supposed to be done:

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL>
SQL> create user new_user identified by new_user
  2  default tablespace users
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session, create table to new_user;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect new_user/new_user
Connected.
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.
```

---

This is what I suspect you did: drop the old user first:

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> drop user new_user cascade;

User dropped.

SQL>
```

Now, start over. Pay attention to **all** double quotes in the following code:

```
SQL> create user "new_user" identified by new_user
  2  default tablespace users
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session, create table to new_user;
grant create session, create table to new_user
                                      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01917: user or role 'NEW_USER' does not exist


SQL> grant create session, create table to "new_user";

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect new_user/new_user
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.
SQL> connect "new_user"/new_user
Connected.
SQL> create table new_user.test (id number);
create table new_user.test (id number)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01918: user 'NEW_USER' does not exist


SQL> create table "new_user".test (id number);

Table created.

SQL>
```

---

See? If you created it using double quotes, every time you reference it, you **must** use double quotes.

I suggest you get rid of them (double quotes) when working with Oracle. That includes users, table names, column names, procedure names, everything.